# Azure messages are handled at the same time

Tags: c#, azure

I have an Azure subscription which listens for messages of a specific type

```
SqlFilter filter = new SqlFilter($"(MessageType = '{ MessageType.ExtendedScan}')");
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(description, filter);
```

My issue is in the handler for these types of messages, I deserialize the message into a .NET class, and call a stored procedure which inserts the message into a SQL Server database. The stored procedure, which cannot be edited, looks for duplicates by comparing 5 fields and it eliminates any duplicates found.

There is one field where I can set the value to any integer value I like. I tried a value which increments, I tried reading/updating from a tracker table, but both approaches suffer from the same issue. The messages are picked up off the Azure queue at the same time, so when I pass in the data to the stored procedure, sometimes the rows evaluate to the same values and I lose data.

In short, the messages in the Azure queue are processed concurrently and I lose data.

Has someone come across this before?

This is related to azure service, message bus.

Comment: I guessing that this is related to Azure Service Bus, although you really should clarify this in your post.